# Javascript get nextSibling not class "foo"

Tags: javascript

I need to  get the next sibling of an element but it should not have the class "foo". In jQuery this would be:

```
myEl.next("div.goodClass")
or
myEl.next().not(".foo")
```

Can this be done with *nextSibling*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (elem.nextSibling && !/(?:^|\s+)foo(?:\s|$)/.test(elem.nextSibling.className)) {
    // there is a next sibling that does not have the class foo
}
```

Comment: sorry, I need to use nextSibling not jQuery for this

Comment: @Mic: What about `class="foobar"`?

Comment: @Mircea: Use `indexOf` only if you are absolutely sure that there is not another class with such a subword.

Answer (score 1):

You can to check the *className* property of *nextSibling* using a regular expression:

```
if (/(?:^|\s)foo(?:\s|$)/.test(el.nextSibling.className)) {
    // next sibling has foo class
}
```

If you want to find the next element that doesn't have that class, you can do something like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("myEl");

while (el = el.nextSibling) {
    if (!(/(?:^|\s)foo(?:\s|$)/.test(el.className)))
        break;
}

// el is either null, or an element that doesn't have the foo class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
x=myEl.nextSibling;
while (x.nodeType!=1)
{
    if(x.className=="foo"){
       x=x.nextSibling;
    }
}
return x;
```